# How to reuse ssh_keypair in packer

Tags: ssh, packer, amazon-ebs, key-pair

So, I’ve tried to build a new image exist snapshot from my ec2 instance with current keypair and having this issue.

Error message:

> 2021/08/31 15:13:42 packer-plugin-amazon_v1.0.0_x5.0_darwin_amd64 plugin: 2021/08/31 15:13:42 [DEBUG] SSH handshake err: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain
> 2021/08/31 15:13:42 packer-plugin-amazon_v1.0.0_x5.0_darwin_amd64 plugin: 2021/08/31 15:13:42 [DEBUG] Detected authentication error. Increasing handshake attempts

> 2021/08/31 15:13:42 ui error: ==> amazon-ebs.vl-template: Error waiting for SSH: Packer experienced an authentication error when trying to connect via SSH. This can happen if your username/password are wrong. You may want to double-check your credentials as part of your debuggin
> g process. original error: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain

Here is my template:

```
source "amazon-ebs" "my-template" {
  profile                 = "${var.profile}"
  region                  = "${var.region}"
  ami_name                = "${var.ami_name}-${local.timestamp}"
  ami_virtualization_type = "hvm"
  communicator            = "ssh"
  ssh_interface           = "public_ip"
  ssh_username         = "${var.ssh_username}"
  ssh_keypair_name     = "${var.ssh_keypair_name}"
  ssh_private_key_file = "${var.ssh_private_key_file}"
  ssh_agent_auth = true
  ssh_timeout    = "10m"
  aws_polling {
    delay_seconds = 60
    max_attempts  = 60
  }
  ebs_optimized     = false
  instance_type     = "${var.instance_type}"
  vpc_id            = "${var.vpc_id}"
  subnet_id         = "${var.subnet_id}"
  security_group_id = "${var.security_group_id}"
  launch_block_device_mappings {
    device_name           = "/dev/sda1"
    volume_size           = "${var.root_volume_size_gb}"
    volume_type           = "${var.volume_type}"
    delete_on_termination = true
  }
  source_ami_filter {
    filters = {
      name                = "${var.filter_name}"
      root-device-type    = "ebs"
      virtualization-type = "hvm"
    }
    most_recent = true
    owners      = ["${var.owner_id}"]
  }
}

build {
  sources = ["source.amazon-ebs.my-template"]
}
```

My packer command:

`packer build -var “ssh_private_key_file=/Users/movmac024/.ssh/mykey.pem” -var “profile=myaws” -var “region=ap-southeast-1” hcl/mytemplate.pkr.hcl`

Comment: If you do not have a valid SSH keypair for this build, then Packer can generate a temporary one for you during the process.

Comment: I do have valid key for ssh. Fun fact,I actually can ssh to the instance when packer bring it up through pubilc ip with my pem key =))

Answer (score 1):

Found out that only use `ssh_private_key_file` or `ssh_agent_auth` when `ssh_keypair_name` is utilized.